# Why is the Android GPU monitor working for 6.0.1, but not 7.1.2?

Tags: android, android-studio, gpu, android-monitor

I want to use the GPU monitor to view statistics for my app.

However, I cannot get the GPU monitor to show any stats for my Google Pixel XL, running 7.1.2, only for my ASUS Nexus running 6.0.1.

It is simply blank.

In my project structure, the Compile SDK version is API 25: Android 7.1.1 (Nougat), and the Build Tools Version is 25.0.3

I want to see the GPU differences between the devices. How can I configure my project so that the GPU monitor will work with Android 7.1.2 ?

Below is my grade file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.deansponholz.fish_game"
    minSdkVersion 22
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
{
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

The problem still persists without a single attempt at a resolution

Literally how long do I have to wait until someone answers this. Its been months.

Comment: Try to update to recent Android Studio 3.0. It introduces new Android Profiler for monitoring.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no fix. Android Studio just doesn't support it. Bad IDE.